# using reformulate to merge non-standard formula

Tags: r, string, formula, eval, paste

Given:

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")
mm_exp <- expression(
  f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE), 
  f(testm2, testmodel = 'fg'),
  f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')
)
```

I want to produce `formula`s using `mm_exp` and all combinations (`combn`) of `vars` to enter in a model:

```
#y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, 
#  truetest2 = TRUE) + f(testm2, testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')

#y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, 
#  truetest2 = TRUE) + f(testm2, testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')

#y ~ var1 + var2 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, 
#  truetest2 = TRUE) + f(testm2, testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')

#y ~ var1 + var4 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, 
#  truetest2 = TRUE) + f(testm2, testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')


#etc.....
```

If I simplify `mm_exp`, I can get something similar to what I want using `reformulate` (ignoring `combn` for now):

```
mm_exp_simplify <- expression(
  f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g), 
  f(testm2, testmodel = 'fg'),
  f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')
)
reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp_simplify, deparse)), "y")
# y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", 
#     testgraph = g) + f(testm2, testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, 
#     testmodel = "fg3")
```

but if I add back in `truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE` it causes issues:

```
mm_exp <- expression(
  f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE), 
  f(testm2, testmodel = 'fg'),
  f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')
)
reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse)), "y")
# Error in reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse)), "y") : 
#   'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
```

I also tried using `quote` but had a similar problem:

```
mm_quote <- quote(
  f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE) + 
    f(testm2, testmodel = 'fg') + f(testm3, testmodel = 'fg3')
)
as.formula(paste0("y ~ ", paste(paste(vars, collapse = "+"), deparse(mm_quote), sep = "+")))
# Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
#   <text>:2:39: unexpected '='
# 1: y ~ var1+var2+var3+var4+f(testm, testmodel = "test", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, 
# 2: y ~ var1+var2+var3+var4+    truetest2 =
#                                          ^
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to include the `truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE` and also how to get the `combn` versions of the formulas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

To solve the first problem, you need to use `deparse1` instead of `deparse`. Like this:

```
reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse1)), "y")
#> y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + f(testm, testmodel = "test", 
#>     testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE) + f(testm2, 
#>     testmodel = "fg") + f(testm3, testmodel = "fg3")
```

---

About your second problem, first you can create all the combinations with all possible lengths, then you can create a list of all formulas in this way:

```
# all vars combinations 
vars_comb <- lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE))
vars_comb <- unlist(vars_comb, recursive = FALSE)

# all formulas
lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(c(v, sapply(mm_exp, deparse1)), "y"))
```

---

### WHY

The reason behind it is related to the default value of the argument `width.cutoff` which is `width.cutoff = 60L` in `deparse` and `width.cutoff = 500L` in `deparse1`.

Just look at this:

```r
# output with deparse
deparse(expression(f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE)))
#> [1] "expression(f(testm, testmodel = \"test\", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, "
#> [2] "    truetest2 = TRUE))"

# output with deparse and width.cutoff forced to 500
deparse(expression(f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE)), 
        width.cutoff = 500)
#> [1] "expression(f(testm, testmodel = \"test\", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE))"

# output with deparse1
deparse1(expression(f(testm, testmodel = 'test', testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE)))
#> [1] "expression(f(testm, testmodel = \"test\", testgraph = g, truetest1 = TRUE, truetest2 = TRUE))"
```

The first `deparse` creates a vector of length 2 which interferes with `reformulate` because it creates components of the formula that are not complaint.

---

### FOR R < 4.0

If you have R 3.6 like you said in the comments, `deparse1` is not available.
Therefore you need to set `width.cutoff = 500L` inside `deparse`.

The solution will look like this:

```
# first issue
reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse, width.cutoff = 500L)), "y")

# second issue
vars_comb <- lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE))
vars_comb <- unlist(vars_comb, recursive = FALSE)
lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(c(v, sapply(mm_exp, deparse, width.cutoff = 500L)), "y"))
```

Comment: ooh I got it, you need some `+` as separator right? okay wait...

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this is a great answer thank you! I hadn't seen `deparse1` before but I see its new in R 4.0. If I wanted to do this with an older version (R 3.6), could I use `reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse(width.cutoff = 500L))), "y")
`- it doesnt work?

Comment: no, you should write it like this: `reformulate(c(vars, sapply(mm_exp, deparse, width.cutoff = 500L)), "y")`